# Selenium Webdriver (Java) Creation a class for Scrolling

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to create a class for different kind of scrolls (Scroll up, down, bottom of page, Etc), but I can't do it work.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ScrollPage {

    public static void scrolldown(String element) throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\JAVA\\DRIVER\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();       

        //Scroll 1/4 página
        JavascriptExecutor jse1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse1.executeScript("scroll(0,250);");
        }
    /*
        public static void scrolldown2(String element) throws Exception {       
        //Scroll hasta la mitad
        JavascriptExecutor jse2 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse2.executeScript("scroll(0,500);");
        }

        public static void scrolldown3(String element) throws Exception {       
        //Scroll hasta el final
        JavascriptExecutor jse3 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse3.executeScript("scroll(0,1000);");
        }
   */   
        //Otra forma de Scroll hasta el final
 /*     JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,Math.max"
                + "(document.documentElement.scrollHeight,"
                + "document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));");

    public static void scrollup(String element) throws Exception {  
        //Scroll hasta arriba
        JavascriptExecutor jse4 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse4.executeScript("scroll(1000,0);");
        }

        public static void slowmotion (String element) throws Exception {   
        //Scroll en cámara lenta
        for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if(second >=60){
                break;
            }
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)", "");
        }


    }
*/
}
```

After that, in another class, I want to call a specific scroll:

ScrollPage.scrolldown();

Please, help me.

Comment: Your question need editing [Howto ask ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Scrollpage slowmotion down, the code is:

```
public static void slowmotionDown(InternetExplorerDriver driver) throws Exception {
        for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if(second >=60){
                break;
            }
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,13)", "");
        }
    }
```

For Scrollpage slowmotion up, the code is:

```
 public static void slowmotionUp(InternetExplorerDriver driver) throws Exception {
        for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if(second >=60){
                break;
            }
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(1000,-13)", "");
        }
    }
```

This is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of errors in your code:

1. You are messing driver instantiation within `scrolldown` method. Remove all non-scroll related stuff from it.
2. For scrolling to work, obviously, some scrollable web-page should be opened. In your scroll method no page is opened - just blank browser start page. Use `driver.get(<some url>)` method for that
3. Once scrollable page is opened - call `(JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");` to scroll window by 250 pixels

Comment: I'm trying to call this class from another class. OOP.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Selenium Java issue, this has to do with object oriented programming.  Are you familiar with how java classes work?

1. Create a new class, called something like ScrollMethods, and put all your scroll methods in that class.
2. In your test, then you just need to instantiate that class:

   ScrollMethods scrollMethods = new ScrollMethods();

Now you should be able call the Scroll Methods within your test class.

Comment: Hi smit9243: I don't remember very wel about the OOP, but that is what I'm trying to do so. I want to call (or invoke) the method in another class from this class.

Comment: I modified my answer, let me know if you any additional questions.

Comment: Sorry, but the issue here was because the Scroll up method (Slow motion) was not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong java Script command to Scroll the window.

Try This :-

```
 JavascriptExecutor jse1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse1.executeScript("window.scroll(0,250);");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues in my code.

The right one would be next:

```html
package Util;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public abstract class ScrollPage {


 public static void doScrollDown250(ChromeDriver driver)throws Exception{
        JavascriptExecutor jse = driver;
        jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250);");
    }
 
    public static void doScrollDown500(ChromeDriver driver)throws Exception {
    JavascriptExecutor jse2 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jse2.executeScript("scroll(0,500);");
    }
     
    public static void doScrollUp(ChromeDriver driver)throws Exception {
        JavascriptExecutor jse2 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse2.executeScript("scroll(0,000);");
        }
     
     
     public static void doScrolldown1000(ChromeDriver driver)throws Exception {  
     JavascriptExecutor jse3 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
     jse3.executeScript("scroll(0,1000);");
     }
      
      //Slow Motion Down
     public static void slowmotionDown(ChromeDriver driver) throws Exception { 
     for (int second = 0;; second++) {
         if(second >=60){
             break;
         }
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,13)", "");
     }
 }
     
     //Slow Motion Up
     public static void slowmotionUp(ChromeDriver driver) throws Exception { 
         for (int second = 0;; second++) {
             if(second >=60){
                 break;
             }
      ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(1000,13)", "");
         }
     }
     
     //From Left to Right
     public static void Left2Right(ChromeDriver driver) throws Exception {   
      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
       js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(2000,0)", "");
     }
     
     //From Right to Left
     public static void Right2Left(ChromeDriver driver) throws Exception {  
      JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;  
      jsx.executeScript("window.scrollBy(-2000,0)", "");
     }
     
     //Scroll Down the Element Web, in this case, Ver Detalles del Plan (Modify the Xpath)
     public static void WebElement (ChromeDriver driver) throws Exception{
      ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", 
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='option1']/div[1]/div[5]/a")));
     }
}
```

After that, in another class, we will call any of these methods with this sentence:

```
ScrollPage.slowmotionDown(driver);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Please remember declarate the imports and the ChromeDriver

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import Util.ScrollPage;
public class banner1 extends ScrollPage {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\JAVA\\DRIVER\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: But I have an issue with trying to Run the Slow Motion Scroll UP:
     //Slow Motion Up
     public static void slowmotionUp(ChromeDriver driver) throws Exception { 
         for (int second = 0;; second++) {
             if(second >=60){
                 break;
             }
      ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(1000,13)", "");
         }
     }